# Combining multiple jQuery animations?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a couple of jQuery animations running in a sequence after certain resources are loaded:

```
$(".loading").delay(2600).fadeOut({
    useTranslate3d: true,
});

$(".zip").delay(1900).slideDown({
    useTranslate3d: true,
});

$("#zip").delay(2800).slideDown({
    useTranslate3d: true,
});
```

Is there a better way to combine all of these animations? It feels superfluous having to write them all out like this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same `options` object for all three animations.

```
var opts = {
    useTranslate3d: true,
}
$(".loading").delay(2600).fadeOut(opts);
$(".zip").delay(1900).slideDown(opts);
$("#zip").delay(2800).slideDown(opts);
```

Having `.zip` and `#zip` pointing to different elements might also be a bit confusing - but that depends on your DOM structure.

Comment: Yeah, I'll worry about the naming later.